# Eclipse StatusManager do not show detail

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Code:

```
Job job = new Job("Connect to Database") { 
            @Override 
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                // 即使是在正常的情况下，某些版本的DB2的连接建立时间也比较长。。。
                monitor.beginTask("正在建立到数据库的连接 ...", 100); 
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    database = new Database(cp.getName(),  cp.getConnection());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    IStatus sqlErrorStatus = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "amarsoft.dbmp", e.getMessage(), null);
                    StatusManager.getManager().handle(sqlErrorStatus, StatusManager.SHOW);
                }
                monitor.done(); 
                return Status.OK_STATUS; 
            } 
        };
```

[image]

How can I make it display the exception's stack trace when user click the 'Details' button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default details area of status dialog does **not** display exception stack trace.

If you have your own Eclipse [product](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/product.htm) then you can customize details and support areas of the status dialog using [org.eclipse.ui.statusHandlers](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_statusHandlers.html) extension point. You will need to extend [`WorkbenchErrorHandler`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/WorkbenchErrorHandler.html) and override `configureStatusDialog(...)` method:

```java
void configureStatusDialog(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager statusDialog) {
    statusDialog.enableDefaultSupportArea(true);
    statusDialog.setDetailsAreaProvider(new CustomStatusAreaProvider());
}

class CustomStatusAreaProvider extends AbstractStatusAreaProvider {
    Control createSupportArea(Composite parent, StatusAdapter statusAdapter) {
        //Create and return details area
    }
}
```

---

By **passing the exception** to `Status` instead of `null` you make the stack trace available for details dialog of error log view.

Comment: not  work. it just display the message(the string   returned by  #exception.getMessage) twice in the detail area.

Comment: @CaiNiaoCoder You are correct, I should have checked it first! Updated my answer.