# Custom error dialog in eclipse e4 application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to change the default status handler of our e4 application, because I want to add the full stack trace to it.

So far, I added the following snippet to the plugin xml:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.statusHandlers"> 
 <statusHandler
        class="our.test.StatusHandler"
        id="custom_status_handler"/>
  <statusHandlerProductBinding
        handlerId="custom_status_handler"
        productId="my_product.product">
  </statusHandlerProductBinding>
</extension>
```

The class our.test.StatusHandler looks as follows:

```
public class StatusHandler extends AbstractStatusHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(StatusAdapter statusAdapter, int style) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work. The default Error dialog is still shown and there is no output in the console.

I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683989/eclipse-statusmanager-do-not-show-detail/9685239#9685239) answer and used WorkbenchErrorHandler instead of AbstractStatusHandler, but it does not work either.

Comment: Anything involving org.eclipse.ui.xxxx is 3.x compatibility mode and can't be used in a pure e4 application. What errors are you trying to handle?

Comment: I want to handle any exception in any plugin. The goal is to show the full stack trace, because the default error dialog only shows the exception's message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StatusHandler is 3.x compatibility mode and isn't used in a pure e4 application.

You can deal with unhandled exceptions by adding an implementation of `IEventLoopAdvisor` in the application context. The `@PostContextCreate` method of the RCP LifeCycle class is a good place to do this:

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext context)
{
  context.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, new EventLoopAdvisor(context));

  ...
}

class EventLoopAdvisor implements IEventLoopAdvisor
{
  private final IEclipseContext _appContext;

  EventLoopAdvisor(IEclipseContext appContext)
  {
    super();

    _appContext = appContext;
  }

  @Override
  public void eventLoopIdle(final Display display)
  {
    display.sleep();
  }

  @Override
  public void eventLoopException(final Throwable exception)
  {
    // Report error
  }
}
```

Note that the call to `display.sleep()` in `eventLoopIdle` is very important.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm :)